# Smooth binary segmentation mask image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to smooth out the outline of my binary image segmentation mask to improve upon the output from my convolutional neural network segmentation algorithm.

I tried PIL:

```
# Smooth the outline
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
pil_img = Image.fromarray(orignal_mask)
smoothed_image = pil_img.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
smoothed_image = smoothed_image.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE)
smoothed_image_arr = np.array(smoothed_image)
smoothed_image_arr[smoothed_image_arr>=127] = 255
smoothed_image_arr[smoothed_image_arr<127] = 0
cv2.imwrite(data_dir + 'test_masks/smooth_{}'.format(jpg_filename), smoothed_image_arr)
```

After thresholding, the resulting image looks essentially identical to the original mask.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there any other way to smooth out the binary mask?  I am open to any Python solution.

[Original Jagged Binary Image Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgryj.jpg)

Comment: You may find this useful! http://answers.opencv.org/question/139537/how-to-smooth-edge-of-text/#140533

Comment: Doesn't it help if you simply dilate/erode the image?

Comment: @Headcrab and repeat if necessary.

Comment: You could get the contour and then reduce the number of vertices using approxPolyDP(). Then redraw the contour as white filled on a black background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I smooth the segmented blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877035/how-can-i-smooth-the-segmented-blob)

Answer (score 1):

You can try OpenCV to apply morphological operation, the opening can slightly smooth the edges:

```
cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3)))
```

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64056653/7328782). If two questions can be answered in the some way, the questions are duplicates. Flag one as a duplicate of the other.